# Using stateflow for mutableList in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata

Working on a project where we need to have a list of items in a view model. The type is a custom data class.

Until now, I have used a `MutableLiveData` to store the state of the list. The list will be updated when a user scans an item on an RFID reader that we have connected to the device. When scanned, an item will be fetched from a server and the list will be updated accordingly.

I want to try and move on to using a `StateFlow` instead, but I'm running into an issue here.

When a new item is scanned, I'm updating the mutable list with the `add` command and later on updating the corresponding item in the list. This does not trigger the `LiveData` or `StateFlow` observers/collectors - but with `LiveData` I could assign the list to itself after I'm done with updating it. (`_listOfItems.value = _listOfItems.value`) as this would notify observers.

This does not work with `StateFlow` however, since it only trigger when the reference changes (which it doesn't since it's the same list, just with new/changed items in it).

I'm aware that there are probably some issues with using a mutable list and coroutines to update the same list, since it might collide if trying to update the list at the same time, or something like that.

**So, generally the question is:** what's the best approach when having a list in a view model and having the UI update whenever the content of the list changes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be impossible to use a MutableList in a StateFlow and make it update because StateFlow always does an equals comparison with the previous value, and since the previous value is an instance of the same list, they will always be considered equal.

You could make this work with SharedFlow, which does not compare values with the previous.

It is however very error prone to use mutable classes with a SharedFlow/StateFlow (or even LiveData) in general because the data could be getting read from and written to from multiple different places. Very hard to manage.

One solution is to create a copy of the list every time you send it to the flow:

```
myMutableStateFlow.value = myMutableList.toList()
```

If you want code that's even easier to manage, possibly at the expense of performance, don't use mutable Lists at all. Use read-only Lists. You could put it in a `var` property, or just modify the `value` of your StateFlow directly.

```
myMutableStateFlow.value += someNewItems
// where myMutableStateFlow's type is a List, not MutableList
```

Comment: That's exactly my issue, that multiple coroutines can alter the list at random times, which might become a problem and some data might be lost.

I get the point of using immutable lists only and then creating a new list with the new item appended. However, in this use case, an already existing item in the list might be updated as well, meaning that I can't just always add an item to the end of the list, as sometimes I will need to update some item that already exists - hence why I tried with mutable lists.

Comment: By using read-only lists, I'm afraid that I might drop some data, if I read out the StateFlow list, alter it and by the time I'm ready to reassign the StateFlow list to my local list, the StateFlow list might have changed.

Comment: You can use the `update` function to atomically update it instead:  `myMutableStateFlow.update { it + someNewItems }`. Regarding your first note, if the items in your list really must also be mutable, they may not be a good fit for reactive programming in the first place. UI code should not have to worry that the data it is reading and trying to display might change while its being used or already displayed. It would be less error-prone to replace items in the list with modified versions when they change.

Comment: To do more complex changes than just adding items, copy to a mutable list and edit that list and return it. `myMutableStateFlow.update { it.toMutableList().apply { /* make list modifications here */ } }`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will look at the update method - however, as mentioned, as I see it, this will only work if I would only need to append new items to the list. The use case is: Scan an item, it gets added to the list, but in a loading state. While loading, a new item gets scanned and added to the list in the loading state. After this, the first item is done loading, and should now be updated with content from a server. Hence, I need to update the existing item with new data. Or, do you recommend that I instead delete the "loading item" and replace it with the new retrieved item?

Comment: Just a question regarding the issue: This might be a totally no-no solution, but would it be possible to just have a regular mutable list (not stateFlow) and then a sharedFlow and then in each method of my view model where I modify the mutable list in some way, I emit the now updated list through the sharedFlow?

Comment: I recommend you delete the loading item and replace it. Yes, you can use SharedFlow with a replay of 1. I highly discourage reusing a MutableList though. There are so many ways you can accidentally misuse it, it’s not worth the hassle.

Comment: Cool, thanks so much for your help! I'll try out with the implementation of using read-only lists by removing and adding updated items back.

Comment: And now for a final practical question: I've tried to implement two different ways of notifying the UI about changes. 
Solution 1: I have a regular `mutableList` and a `sharedFlow` in my view model. Every time I change something in it I do a `sharedFlow.emit(myList)`.
Solution 2: I have a `mutableStateFlow`  of type `List` in my view model. Every time I need to update the list I do: `stateFlow.update { it.toMutableList().apply { // some list changes here // } }`

Which do you think is best? 

Again, thanks so much for your input!