# Ui not recomposing after deleting all items in jetpack compose using Room Database

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a movie application built with jetpack compose. there is section where i'm showing the fav movies that user selected. the favs should perfectly in the ui but when i delete the items from UI, the ui does not recompose immediately to reflect changes. what to do?

This is my UI

```
@Composable
fun FavScreen(
    movieViewModel: MovieViewModel
) {

    remember { mutableStateOf(movieViewModel.getFavMovies()) }
    val shouldShowDialog = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val uiStates = movieViewModel.favs.collectAsState()


    Column {
        Row {
            Text(
                text = "Fav Movies",
                fontSize = 25.sp,
                fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.nsb)),
                modifier = Modifier.padding(20.dp).weight(1f)
            )

            IconButton(onClick = {
                shouldShowDialog.value  = true
            }) {
                Icon(Icons.Filled.Delete, contentDescription = "")
            }
        }
        when(val currentState = uiStates.value){
            is MovieViewModel.UiStates.LOADING -> {
                Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
                    CircularProgressIndicator()
                }
            }
            is MovieViewModel.UiStates.FAVS -> {
                val data = currentState.data
                if(data.isEmpty()){
                    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
                        Text(
                            text = "No Fav Movies",
                            fontSize = 25.sp,
                            fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.nsb)),
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(20.dp))
                    }
                }
                else {
                    LazyColumn(){
                        items(data){ fav ->
                            Row(modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(20.dp)
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
                                .background(color = Color.DarkGray)) {
                                AsyncImage(
                                    model = Utils.IMAGE_URL + fav.imageUrl,
                                    contentDescription = "",
                                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                                    filterQuality = FilterQuality.High,
                                    modifier = Modifier
                                        .width(150.dp)
                                        .height(150.dp))

                                Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(20.dp)) {
                                    Text(
                                        text = fav.title!!,
                                        fontSize = 20.sp,
                                        fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.nsb)))
                                    Text(
                                        text = fav.rating.toString() + "/10 IMDB",
                                        fontSize = 15.sp,
                                        fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.nsb)))
                                    Text(
                                        text = "Movie ID : #" + fav.movieID,
                                        fontSize = 15.sp,
                                        fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.nsb)))
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            is MovieViewModel.UiStates.ERROR -> {
                Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center){
                    Text(
                        text = "No Fav Movies",
                        fontSize = 25.sp,
                        fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.nsb)),
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(20.dp))
                }
            }
            else -> {}
        }
    }
    if (shouldShowDialog.value){
        AlertDialog(
            onDismissRequest = { shouldShowDialog.value = false },
            confirmButton = {
                TextButton(onClick = {
                    movieViewModel.deleteMovies()
                    shouldShowDialog.value = false
                }) {
                    Text(text = "Proceed", fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.nsm)))
                }
            },
            dismissButton = {
                TextButton(onClick = {
                    shouldShowDialog.value = false
                }) {
                    Text(text = "Cancel", fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.nsm)))
                }
            },
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp),
            text = { Text(text = "Favs Deletion",fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.nsb)))},
            title = { Text(text = "Do you want to delete all fav movies ?", fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.nsb)))}
        )
    }
}
```

This is my viewmodel

```
@HiltViewModel
class MovieViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val movieRepoImpl: MovieRepoImpl
) : ViewModel() {
    

    private val _favs : MutableStateFlow<UiStates> = MutableStateFlow(UiStates.INITIAL)
    val favs get() = _favs.asStateFlow()


    // MOVIE DAO
    fun getFavMovies() = viewModelScope.launch {
        try {
            _favs.value = UiStates.LOADING
            movieRepoImpl.getFavs().collectLatest {
                _favs.value = UiStates.FAVS(it)
            }
        } catch (ex : Exception){
            _favs.value = UiStates.ERROR(ex.localizedMessage!!)
        }

    }
    fun insertMovie(favModel: FavModel) = viewModelScope.launch {
        movieRepoImpl.insertFav(favModel)
    }
    fun deleteMovies() = viewModelScope.launch {
        movieRepoImpl.deleteAllMovies()
    }

     sealed class UiStates {
         object LOADING : UiStates()
         data class FAVS(val data : MutableList<FavModel>) : UiStates()
         data class ERROR(val error : String) : UiStates()
         object INITIAL : UiStates()
     }
}
```

Comment: It might help to include the VM code, or at least how it calls the database.

Comment: About what kind of delay are we talking? Is it just a bit laggy, like a 10th of a second? Multiple seconds? Never until the app is restarted? This is most probably caused by how the flow in the viewmodel is updated.

Comment: @Philio I have added viewmodel code , Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue becomes very obvious when you look at write-usages to `_favs`:
Only the `getFavMovies` updates it.

While this sounds like "you should update your ui state in the delete function" i would like to propose an alternative solution:
leveraging the power of `room` + `flows`!

Start by defining a `loadingState` in your ViewModel, which is stored as a flow:

```
sealed class LoadingState {
  object LOADING : LoadingState()
  data class SUCCESS : LoadingState()
  data class ERROR(val error : String) : LoadingState()
  object INITIAL : LoadingState()
}

private val loadingState = MutableStateFlow<LoadingState>(INITIAL)
```

Then, alter your `getFavMovies()` function to use this mechanism:

```
fun getFavMovies() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        try {
            _loadingState.value = LoadingState.LOADING
            movieRepoImpl.loadFavs() // a function which triggers e.g. a network call to actually load your movies
            _loadingState.value = LoadingState.SUCCESS
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            _loadingState.value = LoadingState.ERROR(ex.localizedMessage!!)
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, combine your state + your data, and let the magic happen. This will auto-upate as soon as one of them changes :)

```
val favs: Flow<UiStates> = combine(
    movieRepoImpl.getMovies(),
    loadingState
) { movies, loadingState ->
    when (loadingState) {
        is LoadingState.LOADING -> UiStates.LOADING
        is LoadingState.SUCCESS -> UiStates.SUCCESS(movies)
        is LoadingState.ERROR -> UiStates.ERROR(error)
        is LoadingState. INITIAL -> UiStates.INITIAL
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: there might be typos in that, i have no IDE handy

---

Let's end this answer by improving your code:

1. avoid using `=` for functions which don't return anything (`getFavMovies`, `insertMovie`, `deleteMovies`). Otherwise, you would e.g. expect `getFavMovies` to return a list of Movies
2. `remember { mutableStateOf(movieViewModel.getFavMovies()) }` doesn't really `remember` anything, does it? That's irritating. I suggest moving it into the viewModel: `init { movieViewModel.getFavMovies() }`
3. `val uiStates = movieViewModel.favs.collectAsState()`: Naming implies that this is multiple ui states, please use singular; same for the `UiStates` class itself. Also, if you use ".value" here directly, you can skip the redeclaration here: `when(val currentState = uiStates.value)`
4. Your UiState contains a `MutableList<FavModel>`. Using mutable values for an ui state is a bad idea, e.g. it might confuse your `StateFlow`. Do avoid this. Just use a plain old List :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/72099532/12871582
5. use `collectAsStateWithLifecycle()` instead of `collectAsState()`. See https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/consuming-flows-safely-in-jetpack-compose-cde014d0d5a3
6. you should definitively not access a `RepoImpl` in a viewModel: The whole idea behind splitting the repo into an interface and an implementation is to hide the implementation
7. it's a good idea to define a Screen-Composable which does not need a viewModel, but only data, similar to https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-hoisting:

.

```
@Composable
private fun FavScreen(
  val viewModel: MovieViewModel,
) {
  FawScreen(
    uiState = viewModel.fav.collectAsStateWithLifecycle().value,
    shouldShowDialog = viewModel.shouldShowDialog.collectAsStateWithLifecycle().value
  )
}

@Composable
private fun FavScreen(
  val uiState: UiStates,
  val shouldShowDialog: Boolean
) {
  // your current ui
}
```